# Test express render with locals

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, chai, chai-http

Here is my sample code:

File: index.js

```
var express = required('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    ...
    ...
    res.render("/index", {
        list: data
    });
});
```

File: test.js

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../index');
var should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Homepage', function(done){
    it('should render index view', function(done){
        chai.request(server.app)
        .get("/")
        .end(function(err, res){
            console.log(res.body);
        });
    });
});
```

The `console.log(res.body)` shows output as `{}`. How can I get the local `list` variable to show in the output? I want to test if this local `list` variable has any data in my test.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. You should use [res.json([body])](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) to send the `list` data to your test case.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const data = ['a', 'b'];
  res.json({ list: data });
});

module.exports = { app };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('./index');
var should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Homepage', function (done) {
  it('should render index view', function (done) {
    chai
      .request(server.app)
      .get('/')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  Homepage
{ list: [ 'a', 'b' ] }
    ✓ should render index view


  1 passing (28ms)
```

Option 2. You should assert the view rendered correctly with your `list` data.

`index.js`:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, './views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const data = ['a', 'b'];
  res.render('index', { list: data });
});

module.exports = { app };
```

`views/index.ejs`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <% for (let v of list) { %>
    <p><%= v %></p>
  <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('./index');
var should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Homepage', function (done) {
  it('should render index view', function (done) {
    chai
      .request(server.app)
      .get('/')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        console.log(res.text);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  Homepage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
    <p>a</p>
  
    <p>b</p>
  
</body>
</html>
    ✓ should render index view


  1 passing (32ms)
```